# Is there a football game (Like Fifa or Pes)?

Tags: games

I've downloaded 0ad, and it seems great, I'd love if there was a football (soccer) game as good as 0ad, like Fifa or Pes, I've seen Gameplay Football, but don't know how to install, and if it is safe,because it's not in the official respositories. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just run `apt-cache search football`?

Comment: I did it so, but I haven't found any one...